# Is there a way to alias 'require' to another name?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

We compile our node module to an executable, and embed dependencies so that in order to require our at runtime modules, you use syntax such as

```
const cust_namespace = <bin>_require('custom-namespace');
```

Where our runtime environment knows to resolve _require modules internally.

However, at dev time, the IDE, in this case VSCode, needs to be able to resolve from a typings, so we still need to use:

```
const cust_namespace = require('custom-namespace');
```

My gulpfile has a transform post-transpile which does a search and replace to replace

```
const cust_namespace = require('custom-namespace');
```

with

```
const cust_namespace = <bin>_require('custom-namespace');
```

to give me the best of both worlds. Is this a best practice? Given that the way the binary works is something I have no control over, is there a way to alias _require() so that VScode understands that at dev time, pretend that bin_require() is to be interpreted as require()?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to alias _require() so that VScode understands that at dev time, pretend that bin_require() is to be interpreted as require()

Not easily. `require` understanding is a pattern that is baked into the analysis engine and changing it would require a new config that needs to be piped into the `require` analysis engine. Not worth the effort given its not standard practice.

> Is this a best practice?

Aliasing require is not best practice.

Comment: So, a transform like this is the best way to go?
`code`:

.pipe(replace(`bin_core = require('bin-core');`, `bin_core = bin_require('bin-core');`))